# Weird logout, system freeze and restart problem

Tags: 10.10, freeze

I am having this weird problem where my system will either restart all of a sudden or just freeze. Sometimes it just gets me logged out of Ubuntu and I have to login again.

Not sure if its related, but sometimes programs crash too. Chrome (can be becuause of dev version), Skype etc.

Are there any logs which I can check what happened or if something crashed/failed.

Any tests that I should try running? Memtest or some HDD related perhaps?

P.S. I am running 10.10

**Edit:** The issue has become more serious now. I just faced the issue 10+ times in the last 15 minutes. Twice it got hang and other times I got logged out for no reason.
When the system got hang this time, I saw that Caps lock & Scroll lock were blinking.

Could it be because of some programs?

Comment: Can you list all the third-party programs that you have installed?

Comment: @alexy13 Since 11.04 is out, I will try doing a fresh install. It would be better not to have to debug this down. If the problem comes up again, somehow because of what I have installed & using, then I will get back to this question.

Comment: I did a fresh install of 11.04 so this problem is solved but I will leave the question open in case someone wants to fill in the details of how to troubleshoot in such a case.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).